# The meaning of "be up for/be up to" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can "be up for/to" be used to mean eligible for something or ready for something.

> This computer is not up for/to fixing because its warranty has been
> expired.
>
> This computer is not up for/to fixing because it's badly crashed.

Comment: Neither of your examples are about real life situations. Computers can be fixed after the warranty has expired, and they can often simply be re-started after they have crashed.

Comment: What does it have to do with the issue raised in my question? It's not about real life situations.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer 'up to'.

We can use 'up to' to mean 'capable of'. An old person may not be up to a five-mile run. A car with a seized engine may not be up to being repaired, if the cost of that is more than the car is worth.

In the UK we would use 'up for' about a person meaning 'ready, willing, or enthusiastic' about something. I might be up for a visit to the pub with my best friend; my mother is always up for a cup of tea.

Comment: Actually my mother would also be up for the pub visit. She likes my pal, and would talk to him all the time about films.

Comment: Why "the pub visit" not "a pub visit"?

Comment: @user1425 I could have used '**a** pub visit', if I had been mentioning it for the first time, but in this case I was writing about **the** pub visit that I had previously mentioned (above, in my answer) in connection with my best friend.  The definite article ('the') is used before a noun to define it as something specific (e.g., something previously mentioned or known, something unique, or something being identified by the speaker).